# ListView - Custom Adapter - Database

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

Android 2.3.3

I have a table in database with two columns. I wish to retrieve this data and show them in a ListView having two textviews(first column in first textview and second column in second textview) and repeat this till for all the rows in the database. I have read a few examples on(custom adapter and listview) how to do, but the more I read, the more I get confused.

Can someone give me a head start on how to do this? I can use a dynamic listview, but I wish to do it using the static one.

Here is the Layout of the row in the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Expression"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:text="Expression"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Result"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:text="Result"
        android:textColor="#316DA2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the XML with ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="HISTORY"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="#316DA2"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvHistory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am retrieving the data from database and storing it in a Cursor. I want to read data from Cursor and give those values to the textviews in the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a table in database with two columns. I wish to retrieve this
>   data and show them in a ListView having two textviews(first column in
>   first textview and second column in second textview) and repeat this
>   till for all the rows in the database. I have read a few examples
>   on(custom adapter and listview) how to do, but the more I read, the
>   more I get confused.

Hello. This algorithm is not too tricky. You need to these steps:

1. Create some method for getting rows from db. You can return either
   `List<TableDataType>` or directly `Cursor`.
2. Create subclass of some `ListAdapter` to get better control over it.
3. Set `ListAdapter` to `ListView`.

### Example:

Method for getting data from db:

```
public List<DataType> getAll() {
   List<DataType> objects = new ArrayList<DataType>();
   DataType child = null;
   Cursor c = null;    
   try {
      String query = "select * from TableName";
      c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
      if (c.moveToFirst()) {
         child = new DataType();
         child.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
         child.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
         objects.add(child);  
      }
      return objects;
   }
   finally {
      if (c != null) {
         c.close();
      }
      if (db != null) {
         db.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Then you can create own Adapter extending from `BaseAdapter` and set data to `TextView`s in `getView()` method and create `RowHolder` that will be arbitrary Object that holds childs(widgets) of each row

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   if (convertView == null) {
      // inflate convertView and add row to RowHolder
      // set RowHolder as tag of row .. convertView.setTag(rowHolder);
   }
   else {
      // just recycle views so get existing RowHolder
      rowHolder = (RowHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }
   // set data to widget(s)
   rowHolder.getFirstTextView().setText(dataSource.get(position).getId());
   ...

}
```

`RowHolder` can looks like

```
public class RowHolder {

   private View row;
   private TextView idColumn;

   public RowHolder(View v) {
      this.row = v;
   }

   public TextView getIdColumn() {
      if (idColumn == null) {
         idColumn = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.idColumnId);
      }
      return idColumn;


   }
}
```

And finally set Adapter to `ListView` and work is done.

### Note:

`DataType` is own defined Object. It presents Table in your db where properties of Object are identical with columns in Table.

There is other approach and return from db Cursor and a usage of `SimpleCursorAdapter` or `CursorAdapter`. Here are nice examples:

- [Android Listview Example using CursorAdapter and SQLite
  database](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html)
- [SimpleCursorAdapters and
  ListViews](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)

Answer (score 1):

you should follow this flow

step 1 -> get data from data base and Fill the List   with getter Setter

Step 2 -> Create BaseAdapter Class and give that list in this class[Here you need to see BaseAdpter bind methods]

Stap 3  -> Bind BaseAdapter object with Your ListView

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is take a look at [Bind the List view from Database with Cursor Adapter](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/).
Also check the [ListView Example using Cursor Adapter with SQLiteDatabase](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html).

I hope this will guide you.

Thanks.